# SQL command not properly ended trying to join three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am trying to do this SQL statement, and currently stuck. [this is the code that I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqlPw.png)
The idea is am I am trying to join three tables together which are Employees,Departments,Locations
The Questions is **

- Whose employee have (2) two departments but of the same city?

**
If it is possible to please give me what I did wrong in the code.

Comment: the semicolon you wrote at first 'on' clause  put this on second one

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images - or even worse - links to images.

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [Oracle Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/toc.htm) are different software packages (even if they are currently produced by the same company). They both implement SQL but they extend it in different ways and sometimes they use different syntax conventions that render the queries incompatible between them. Please use only the tags that match the software you are using.

Comment: No pictures, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have one FROM clause and I suggest using joins. Try this:

```
SELECT e.firstname, e.salary+1000, d.department_name, e.department_id, l.city
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
INNER JOIN locations l ON d.location_id = l.location_id
```